# Autocompletion based on filenames in a directory

Tags: function, autocomplete, zsh, aliases

I want to have a function in my zsh for faster accessing my todo-files. It should look inside the folder `~/tasks` where i put my todo-lists and stuff. Now i want to type `task p` and when I hit tab, it should use the files in that directory for autocompletition. Can anyone point me some direction? Or share some snippet to work with?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would seem to do the trick:

```
compdef '_files -W "$HOME/tasks"' task
```